# Trying to follow GROUP BY logic in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm prepping for an SQL interview and was going over this guide.

The eventual code the author wrote was:

```
SELECT cust_id,
       first_name,
       sum(total_order_cost)
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.cust_id
GROUP BY cust_id,
         first_name
```

MY QUESTION:
Why is first_name used in the GROUP_BY? If I wrote the code without first_name in the GROUP BY, I'm getting errors.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you need to GROUP on all the fields that you are not using in an AGGREGATE function.  Or, other formulated, when not grouping on `first_name` what value for `first_name` should be selected? The minimal value, the maximal value, the average value, or .......?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` (`cust_id` and `first_name` in this case) need to be listed in the `GROUP BY`. Even in cases like this one, where there's (presumably) only one `first_name` per `cust_id`, the DB engine still expects every column in the `SELECT` to either be in an aggregate function or in the `GROUP BY`.